# Chroot environment complain about cross compiling (gentoo stage3 mips)

Tags: compilation, mips, chroot, gentoo

I took the stage3 (experimental mips32 - [stage3-mips32-20140904.tar.bz2](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/experimental/mips/stages/mips32/2014/stage3-mips32-20140904.tar.bz2)) Gentoo tarball and put it on my Ubuntu14x64. I set `binfmt` in cooperation with `qemu` to support mips binaries, mounted `/dev`, `/proc` and so on and `chroot`ed to the unpacked tarball. I `emerge --sync`-ed and it suggested me to do a `emerge --oneshot portage` at the end. And so I did. The problem is if it gets down to compiling it says:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-exec-2.0.2/work/python-exec-2.0.2_build':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Is there any variable read from the host (maybe via `/proc`) making the ditro think it is cross compiling? How can I redeem that?

PS: [logfiles](http://www36.zippyshare.com/v/Rp7OOepA/file.html)

Comment: You can use `uname -m` to check your architecture. You may be experiencing this issue: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105754

Comment: Please post logs to pastebin or similar.